# RSS Feeds replacing characters?

Tags: c#, .net, rss

I am currently creating a RSS feed linked to a custom built news column. The news column uses a series of query strings in order to direct the user to a specific post or posts! However the problem I am facing is that the rss feed is replacing some of these query strings with random numbers. For instance:

```
http://www.correlatesearch.com/news.aspx?cat=BusinessManagementControls&nw=
```

&nw= is being replace with

```
&amp;
```

Can anyone direct to a way around this??

Many thanks!

Comment: Has `&nw=` been fully replaced with `&amp;`, or just the `&` part of it?

Comment: Where are those `random numbers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're looking at the raw RSS - which is XML. Within XML, `&` has to be escaped as `&amp;`. This is far from "random numbers".

I suspect you'll find that `&nw=` is *actually* being escaped to `&amp;nw=` - in which case it's not actually changing your content at all. It's representing the text of your URL in an XML-appropriate way. When the XML is read by a client, it will (or should) understand it appropriately.

Comment: I'll bet the random numbers are things like `&#34;` (double quote), etc.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Could be... which may be appropriate within an attribute, but unnecessary within an element. Either way, it's probably appropriate to just leave it :)

Comment: yeah, I'm in the "that's normal" camp.

Answer (score 1):

Is the feed an XML document? Then the replacement **should** take place. It is called escaping character entities.

And I don't see any "random numbers" that you referred to...